# Ansible We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML Shell: vars

Tags: syntax, ansible

I am tying to run this ansible script.

```
---
- name: User MOTD Script
  hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:

      - name: "defaultMOTD"
        prompt: "Do you want to set the MOTDs to the default? (y/n)"
        private: no

      - name: "MOTD"
        prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/motd: "
        private: no
        when: defaultMOTD != "y"

      - name: "MOTDIssue"
        prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue: "
        private: no
        when: defaultMOTD != "y"

      - name: "MOTDIssueNet"
        prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue.net: "
        private: no
        when: defaultMOTD != "y"

  tasks:

  #Set custom MOTDs
  - name Set /etc/motd to user value
    shell: echo "{{ MOTD }}" > /etc/motd
    when: defaultMOTD != "y"
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context

The error appears to be in '/root/NessusScripts/motd.yml': line 29, column 10, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  - name Set /etc/motd to user value
    shell: echo "{{ MOTD }}" > /etc/motd
         ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

I can't workout if this is a syntax error, o you simply can't pass ansible vars through a `shell` command. I based the formatting on from the excerpt here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, your YAML syntax is incorrect.

```
  - name Set /etc/motd to user value
    shell: echo "{{ MOTD }}" > /etc/motd
    when: defaultMOTD != "y"
```

The YAML parser tries to read this list item as a scalar value because that's what the first line is, and then unexpectedly encounters a mapping. You should have:

```
  - name: Set /etc/motd to user value
    shell: echo "{{ MOTD }}" > /etc/motd
    when: defaultMOTD != "y"
```

Answer (score -1):

copy the content and delete the old file, create a new yml file, and paste the same content, it may work.